# Cannot get a message to go to a SQL Server Service Broker Queue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to setup a simple SQL Server Service Broker messaging setup.  I am following the MS tutorials, but I cannot get the following code to work.  Everything runs fine, but the message does not appear on the queue.  Can anyone identify the problem.

Thanks for any help.

```
-- This query returns "1"
SELECT
    Is_Broker_Enabled
FROM Sys.Databases
WHERE Name = 'ActivationTest2';
GO

-- Create the message types.
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE TestRequestMessage VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML;
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE TestReplyMessage VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML;

-- Create the contract.
CREATE CONTRACT TestContract (
    TestRequestMessage SENT BY INITIATOR, 
    TestReplyMessage SENT BY TARGET) ;

-- Create the target queue and service.
CREATE QUEUE ActTestTgtQueue;
CREATE SERVICE ActTestTgtService ON QUEUE ActTestTgtQueue;

-- Create the initiator queue and service.
CREATE QUEUE ActTestInitQueue;
CREATE SERVICE ActTestInitService ON QUEUE ActTestInitQueue;
GO

-- Start a conversation, send the request message.
DECLARE
    @initdlghandle uniqueidentifier,
    @requestmsg nvarchar (100) ;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN DIALOG @initdlghandle 
    FROM SERVICE ActTestInitService 
    TO SERVICE 'ActTestTgtService' 
    ON CONTRACT TestContract 
    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;

SET @requestmsg = N'<RequestMsg>Message for tgt service</RequestMsg>';

-- This returns a GUID and the message text above.
SELECT
    @requestmsg AS Sentrequestmsg
  , @initdlghandle AS Handle;

SEND ON CONVERSATION @initdlghandle 
    MESSAGE TYPE TestRequestMessage (@requestmsg) ;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
-- Check the queue for messages.
-- THIS RETURNS ZERO ROWS.
SELECT
    *
FROM ActTestTgtQueue;
GO
```

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58339/sql-server-servie-broker-with-cross-db-working-fine-with-sql-server-2008-r2

Answer (score 7):

Look at the `transmission_status` column in `sys.transmission_queue` in your database:

```
use <testdb>;
go

select transmission_status, * 
from sys.transmission_queue;
go
```

The status will tell what the issue is.

Comment: The transmission_status is: "Service Broker received an error message on this conversation. Service Broker will not transmit the message; it will be held until the application ends the conversation."

Comment: Sry didn't have time to reply on time. The error message could be also discovered in your initiator queue: `SELECT cast(message_body as XML), * FROM ActTestInitQueue`. At least you now know not only what the problem was, but also how to [Troubleshoot Dialogs](http://rusanu.com/2005/12/20/troubleshooting-dialogs/)

Comment: An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue. Error: 15404, State: 11. Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'DESKTOP-1LPUEOV\Hassan', error code 0x534.
i'm using service broker in conduction with one simple queue and service, and C# SqlDependency library

Comment: @deadManN please ask questions as separate questions, not as comments

Comment: Since i follow you i did this, BTW, it fixed by rename user directly from DBMS, now i get invalid inside my C# code, not related to this forum any more. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a very frustrating evening, I found the answer.

Thank you Remus for your help.

I took the advice in [THIS LINK](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-troubleshoot-service-broker-problems), and in the "Broker:Message Undeliverable" EventClass in SQL Server Profiler, I finally found a more descriptive error message:
"This message could not be delivered because the targeted service does not support the service contract. Targeted service: 'ActTestTgtService', service contract: 'TestContract'."

Looking at the documentation [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190332.aspx), if you do not specify the contract that a service can communicate with, it can only initiate messages, not be the target.  Once I changed the following line, it worked fine:

```
create service ActTestTgtService on queue ActTestTgtQueue (TestContract);
```